# log4j-Jboss-size based - RollingAppender

Tags: java, log4j

Can some one help me in creating log files based on size?

Here is the XML I am using. But this is not working as expected.

The file `engine.log` is getting deleted as soon as the file size reaches 1KB and  a new file with same name is created.

But the old file should be renamed as `engine1.log` or something like that.

```
<!--  A size based file rolling appender -->
<appender name="Engine" class="org.jboss.logging.appender.RollingFileAppender">
    <errorHandler class="org.jboss.logging.util.OnlyOnceErrorHandler"/>
    <param name="File" value="${jboss.server.log.dir}/archivist/engine/engine.log"/>
    <param name="Threshold" value="DEBUG"/> 
    <param name="Append" value="false"/>
    <param name="MaxFileSize" value="1KB"/>
    <param name="MaxBackupIndex" value="3"/>

    <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
        <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%d %-5p [%c] %m%n"/>
    </layout>
</appender>
```

Answer (score 2):

Please try the conversion pattern:

```
<param name="ConversionPattern" value="%d %-5p  [%c{1}] %m %n" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you try to omit this line from your config:

```
<param name="Append" value="false"/>
```

Comment: @user972290 Can you post your full log4j.xml?